# How to get "Enums" objects in a class by reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

I have this class:

```
public class user
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public EyeColor EyeColor { get; set; }
}
public enum EyeColor
{
    Brown,
    Black
}
```

I can use `user.GetType().GetProperties();` to get properties and then get values of them. 
But for enums is different, all I want to do is: getting Enum index, for example brown is `0` and black is `1` for dynamic search on enum fields.
But I have a generic method to get index and I can't use `int enumIndex = (EyeColor)user.EyeColor;` because I don't know what kind of enum will be pass to the generic method.

```
public static IQueryable<T> CreateEqualExpressions<T>(IQueryable<T> query, object model)
{
    var result = query;
    var propertiesToSearch = model.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(x => Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(EqualSearchAttribute)))
        .ToList();
    if (propertiesToSearch.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in propertiesToSearch)
        {
            var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue?.ToString()))
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
                var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo.Name);
                if (propertyValue is string)
                    propertyValue = propertyValue.ToString()?.Trim();
                var constantValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
                var equal = Expression.Equal(property, constantValue);
                var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equal, parameter);
                result = result.Where(exp);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Everything is ok for strings but for enums not works because `propertyValue` is: `Brown` or `Black`, but for dynamic search, I need to index of them like `0` or `1`.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0

Comment: "but for dynamic search, I need to index of them like 0 or 1" Are you sure? What expression are you trying to create? I don't think you can create an `Expression.Equal` with the LHS being `EyeColor` and the RHS being an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need `Convert.ToInt64` to convert the enum value to a `long`, which fits every enum underlying type.

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(model);
if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum) {
    long underlyingEnumValue = Convert.ToInt64(value);
    // construct your expression here...
}
```

Note that if you are constructing an `Expression.Equal`, with one of the operands being the `EyeColor` property access, you should convert that to `long` too:

```
var equal = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Convert(property, typeof(long)), 
    Expression.Constant(underlyingEnumValue)
);
```

Example code:

```
var prop = typeof(User).GetProperty("EyeColor")!;
var value = prop.GetValue(new User() { EyeColor = EyeColor.Black });
var underlyingEnumValue = Convert.ToInt64(value);

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Property(p, prop), 
            typeof(long)), Expression.Constant(underlyingEnumValue)
    ), p
);

var del = lambda.Compile();
var result1 = del.DynamicInvoke(new User() { EyeColor = EyeColor.Brown });
var result2 = del.DynamicInvoke(new User() { EyeColor = EyeColor.Black });

Console.WriteLine(result1); // False
Console.WriteLine(result2); // True
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
var type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
if (type.IsEnum)
{
  var enumIndex = (int) propertyValue;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ```propertyInfo.PropertyType``` returns ```System.Nullbale``` . Is there any method like ```GetProperties``` to get ```Enums``` ? I think a method like ```GetEnums``` will solving my problem.

Comment: `propertyInfo.GetValue` will give you nullable, but since it is an enum, it always have value.. so it is safe..

Comment: @MiladAhmadi [`propertyInfo.PropertyType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype?view=net-6.0) absolutely does not return `System.Nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

if Property is enum then you can try this also

```
object underlyingValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()));
```